# Total inputs from starting price & swap image depending on selected radio & checkboxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to complete a script that is for a Build & Price a RV with several options. I have given a shot on the code, but I can't get either the "Total" price to calculate to work or the "image switch" to work.

On the "Total" script, I need to change it to have a starting price of 39,950.00. Not sure how to adjust it. I got this script here: http://jsfiddle.net/b3p4r/

On the "image switch" script, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I got the script here, but that script didn't have checkboxes... so I'm not sure what I have wrong here. [Display image depending on two input radio buttons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841042/display-image-depending-on-two-input-radio-buttons?rq=1)

**IMAGE SWITCH explanation...**

My idea for this script is that all the images are formatted so regardless if an option is selected, the switch would build the image url...

How I think it should work... there are the following values to be determined.

**graphicsValue** - builds the first part of the image. There is a default value here if needed. It's a radio, so one will be selected.

**awningValue** - builds next section of image URL. There is a default value here if needed. It's a radio, so one will be selected.

**kingValue** - builds third section of image URL... if not checked, this section would be have no value

**solarValue** - builds fourth section of image URL... if not checked, this section would be have no value

**genbaskValue** - builds last section of image URL include the .jpg extension. If not checked, it returns only .jpg to complete the entire image URL

So if **Graphic style 3 is selected (gr-3)**, **Gray Awning (awn-gray)**, **King-Dome is checked (opt-king)**, **Solar is not checked (opt-solar)**, and **Generator Basket is checked (opt-genbask)**... it returns values for those in real time as you toggle each of these selections, the image switches.

In the example above the returned URL would be

/images/build/Red/RB + GA + KD + (nothing) + BA.jpg to equal=
**/images/build/Red/RBGAKD.jpg** (this is the image that would be shown. Or at least this is how I would like for it to work... but it isn't.)

```
  <script type='text/javascript'> // Script for image swap
  $("input:radio[name='graphics'], input:radio[name='awning'], input:checkbox[name='opt-king'], input:checkbox[name='opt-solar'], input:checkbox[name=opt-'genbask']").click(function() { // This handler runs when any of the radio buttons are clicked.
      var graphicsValue = $("input:radio[name='graphics']:checked").id(); // Find which graphics radio button is checked.
      var awningValue = $("input:radio[name='awning']:checked").id(); // Find which awning radio button is checked.
      var kingValue = $("input:checkbox[name='opt-king']:checked").id(); // Find if opt-king checkbox button is checked.
      var solarValue = $("input:checkbox[name='opt-solar']:checked").id(); // Find if opt-solar checkbox button is checked.
      var genbaskValue = $("input:checkbox[name='opt-genbask']:checked").id(); // Find if opt-genbask checkbox button is checked.

      var image_name = ""; // Initialize the image name to blank. We will be appending as we go.

      switch (graphicsValue) {
          case 'gr-1':
              image_name += "/images/build/Black/BL"; // Graphic Style 1 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
          case 'gr-2':
              image_name += "/images/build/Black2/BL"; // Graphic Style 2 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
          case 'gr-3':
              image_name += "/images/build/Red/RB"; // Graphic Style 3 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
          case 'gr-4':
              image_name += "/images/build/Red/RB"; // Graphic Style 4 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
           case 'gr-5':
              image_name += "/images/build/Blue/BU"; // Graphic Style 5 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
          case 'gr-6':
              image_name += "/images/build/Blue/BU"; // Graphic Style 6 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
           case 'gr-7':
              image_name += "/images/build/Pinstripe/Pin"; // Graphic Style 7 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
          case 'gr-8':
              image_name += "/images/build/Pinstripe/Pin"; // Graphic Style 1 was selected, so use that value for the first part of the image.
              break;
          default:
              image_name += "/images/build/Black/BL"; // Make sure there is a default value, or a broken image could occur!
              break;
      }

      switch (awningValue) {
          case 'awn-gray':
              image_name += "GA"; // Gray Awning was selected, so use that value for the second part of the image.
              break;
          case 'awn-blue':
              image_name += "BA"; // Blue Awning was selected, so use that value for the second part of the image.
              break;
          default:
              image_name += "BA"; // Make sure there is a default value, or a broken image could occur!
              break;
      }

       switch (kingValue) {
          case 'opt-king':
              image_name += "KD"; // King-Dome was selected, so use that value for the third part of the image.
              break;

          default:
              image_name += ""; // The default value for the checkbox in default state of not being checked. 
              break;
      }

       switch (solarValue) {
          case 'opt-solar':
              image_name += "SO"; // Solar was selected, so use that value for the fourth part of the image.
              break;

          default:
              image_name += ""; // The default value for the checkbox in default state of not being checked.
              break;
      }

       switch (genbaskValue) {
          case 'opt-genbask':
              image_name += "BA.jpg"; // Generator Basket was selected, so use that value for the last part of the image.
              break;

          default:
              image_name += ".jpg"; // The default value for the checkbox in default state of not being checked. This adds .jpg to complete image if Generator Basket is not checked.
              break;
      }

      $('#show_image_text').text(image_name); // Put the image URL
      $('#Show_image').attr('src', image_name); // Put the image value in the formula image field src.
  });
  </script>
```

The next script is what is used to format the Total Price. I can get this to work if I want to display this as an input, but I want this displayed in a div. I also need to figure out how to add the starting price here.

```
                       <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
window.onload=function(){
function formatCurrency(num) {
  num = num.toString().replace(/\$|\,/g,'');
  if(isNaN(num))
   {num = "0";}
  sign = (num == (num = Math.abs(num)));
  num = num.toFixed(2);
  elements= num.split(".");
  num = elements[0];
  cents = elements[1];
  for (var i = 0; i < Math.floor((num.length-(1+i))/3); i++)
  {num = num.substring(0,num.length-(4*i+3))+','+
   num.substring(num.length-(4*0+3));}
  return (((sign)?'':'-') + '$' + num + '.' + cents)
}

$("input").change(function() {
    var total = 0;
    $("input").each(function() {
        if($(this).is(":checked"))
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
    });
    $("#total").val(formatCurrency(total));
});
}//]]>  

</script>


  </head>
```

This is the HTML I am using...

```
  <body>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <div style="background: #efefef; width: 600px; padding: 10px;">
  <h3>Image Will be shown in this div</h3>
  <img id="show_image" />
  <img id="show_image_text" />
  </div>

  <div><h2 style=" text-align: left; color: #c84e1e !important;"><span style="font-size:20px; color: #222;">MSRP:</span> $<span id="total">39950.00</span></h2></div>



  <form name="build">
  <h2>Floor Plans</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="floorplan" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="fp-stand" value="0.00" > Standard Floor Plan</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="floorplan" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="fp-tb" value="0.00" > Twin Bed Floor Plan</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <h2>Graphics</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-1" value="0.00" > Black/Gray Style 1</div> 
  </div> 
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-2" value="0.00"> Black/Gray Style 2</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-3" value="0.00"> Red/Blue Style 1</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-4" value="0.00"> Red/Blue Style 2</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-5" value="0.00"> Dark Blue/Light Blue Style 1</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-6" value="0.00"> Dark Blue/Light Blue Style 2</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-7" value="0.00"> Pinstripe Style 1 </div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="graphics" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="gr-8" value="0.00"> Pinstripe Style 2</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <h2>Awnings</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="awning" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="awn-gray" value="0.00"> Gray</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title"><input type="radio" name="awning" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="awn-blue" value="0.00"> Blue</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <h2>Flooring</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Montreal<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flooring" id="floor-montreal" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 1)"> $0 (Standard Option) </div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Canyon<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flooring" id="floor-canyon" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 2)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Parador<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="flooring" id="floor-parador" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 3)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Flagstone<br />
  <input type="radio" name="flooring" id="floor-flagstone" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 4)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>



  <h2>Fabrics</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Black Marble<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="fabric" id="fab-marble" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 1)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Mink<br />
  <input type="radio" name="fabric" id="fab-mink" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 2)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Ocean<br />
  <input type="radio" name="fabric" id="fab-ocean" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 3)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>


  <h2>Countertops</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Standard Countertops & Accents<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="fg-counter" id="count-stand" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="0.00" onClick="check_value(this, 5)"> $0 (Standard Option)</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Paradise Beach Fiber-Granite<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="fg-counter" id="count-pb" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="1800.00" onClick="check_value(this, 1)"> $1,800</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Tahoe Fiber-Granite<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="fg-counter" id="count-tahoe" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="1800.00" onClick="check_value(this, 3)"> $1,800</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Baltic Fiber-Granite<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="fg-counter" id="count-baltic" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="1800.00" onClick="check_value(this, 2)"> $1,800</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Dakota Fiber-Granite<br /> 
  <input type="radio" name="fg-counter" id="count-dakota" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="1800.00" onClick="check_value(this, 4)"> $1,800</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>



  <h2>Options</h2>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">King-Dome<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-king" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-king" value="1500.00"> $1,500</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Solar Package<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-solar" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-solar" value="1800.00"> $1,800</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Additional Awning<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-awning" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-awning" value="900.00"> $900</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Generator Quick Connect<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-genquick" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-genquick" value="469.00"> $469</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Generator Basket<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-genbask" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-genbask" value="250.00"> $250</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">30lb Propane Tank Upgrade<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-30pro" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-30pro" value="99.00"> $99</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Four Trojan T-105 Batteries<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-batt-t105" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-batt-t105" value="400.00"> $400</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Four Trojan AGM Batteries<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-batt-agm" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-batt-agm" value="900.00"> $900</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"</div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Wireless Back Up Camera<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-cam" id="opt-cam" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="700.00"> $700</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Front Propane Quick Connect<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-front-proconnect" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-front-proconnect" value="170.00"> $170</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Back Propane Quick Connect<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-back-proconnect" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-back-proconnect" value="160.00"> $160</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Four Reading Light Package<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-read" id="opt-read" style="margin-top:-3px;" value="199.00"> $199</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Large Inverter<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-large-inv" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-large-inv" value="1200.00"> $1,200</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="build-option">
  <div class="build-left">
  <div class="build-title">Small Inverter<br /> 
  <input type="checkbox" name="opt-small-inv" style="margin-top:-3px;" id="opt-small-inv" value="250.00"> $250</div>
  </div>
  <div class="build-right"></div>
  </div>


  </form>
  </div>

  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: I can get the total to work if I put it as an input, but I need to display it in a div. Not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edit 2:

As promised, a working version of your code:
http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/PL6fU/

you had some errors in it, like:

```
$("#total").html(formatCurrency(total));
```

- a DIV (normally) doesn't have a attribute 'value'. You must use html() to make it visible.
- check_value is not given in your code, so i made a dummy.

Overall, i think this is what you want. If not, keep me updated and i will fix it!

**NOTE:** The code is FAR from safe. I'm not sure what you are planning to do with the code. JavaScript is run locally and can break easily (for example on an old computer with Internet Explorer 6).

Never rely too much on JavaScript. If you are going to use the code for purchases, i must advise you that a client can easily change values.

**Tips**:

- If possible, encapsulate your code in functions/classes. Never duplicate code you've written before.
- Again, separate LOGIC from data. The switch cases contains urls of images, which is to me data.
- You can easily write a simple loop that builds the whole html. This reduces html and javascript code. If you want to change something, you can just apply a single rule to change the whole format!
- Think about architecture. There is a high chance that you are not the last person that will look into the code. If someone wants to change this code, it will take ages.. That's why you separate the code from data (using for example JSON). Then if they want to add another checkbox, they can just add a single JSON line to make it work!

---

JEEZ! It took ages to refactor the code. First of all, it is highly recommended to separate your data and your logic.. This will improve debugging and allows others to view the code on a normal way.

It took me **TWO** (!!) hours to make the code working. And then five minutes to add your desired functionality.

Never.. again! Haha

These are the steps:

- store a variable with the (start+)total price
- automatically generate fields/structure from JSON.
- add listeners to them.
- click click click..

Hope it helps (**FULL WORKING VERSION**):
http://jsfiddle.net/kychan/rSVP7/7/embedded/result/

```
//    storage of price (global).
var total = 39950;

//    create list from JSON.
createList();

//    show price in test div at start.
priceView.html(formatCurrency(total));

//    function to update price on change.
function update(box) {
    //    calculate the price from the value of the selected box.
    var price = parseInt(box.value, 10);
    price = (isNaN(price)) ? 0 : price;

    //    if it is selected, you add the price.
    if (box.checked) total += price;

    //    if not, then remove the price.
    else total -= price;

    //    show the price on a test div.
    priceView.html(formatCurrency(total));

    //    the image to load.
    //img.html('<img src="{0}" />'.f($(box).data('img')));
    img.html($(box).data('img'));
}
```

Comment: Wow. I hate you spent that much time on it. I'm not sure what the benefits of JSON are and for what I need to do with this, I don't think it will work. Each set of radio buttons are styled in the actual script with images and modal popups. Are working version is here: http://olivertraveltrailers.com/build-your-ollie/

Comment: I need the main image to change based on the switch script or something similar to create the actually image that should appear. I'll edit original question to edit what I'm trying to do on the image side.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the late response. It was 4am already so i needed some sleep. I would try to make a new fiddle soon.

Comment: Benefits of JSON is that your code (logic) is separated from the data. This prevents a huge dump of code like you've placed and makes all the code neat. This also applies to CSS. Try to avoid as many inline css or (anonymous/global) javascript functions. More: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/10-essential-principles-of-the-javascript-masters--net-895 and **SOLID**: http://www.infoq.com/news/2014/01/solid-principles-javascript

Comment: I have this working... except I need it to actually display the image instead of just display the URL as text. How can I accomplish this? See JS Fiddle Here: http://jsfiddle.net/PL6fU/27/